# Configure JAX-WS @WebServiceRef client from outside the application

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, jax-ws

I want to configure a managed JAX-WS client (injected with `@WebServiceRef`) **from outside the application**, preferably using WebLogic Admin Console.

For example, set the username and password that will be sent in the HTTP request to authenticate on the server when performing the Web Service call.

To be clear, doing it manually requires me to implement it, while using a feature provided by the container requires only configuration.

I was able to do it using SAP NetWeaver, is it possible to do it with WebLogic?

```
@Stateless
public class HolidayClientImpl {

    // I want this dependency to be already configured, instead of doing it myself.
    @WebServiceRef
    private MyRemoteService myRemoteService;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot I didn't find this functionality to be available in WebLogic. It doesn't exist, at least at version 10.3.6 and 12 as well.

That means you have to implement the client configuration, something like this:

```
MyPort port = service.getHTTPPort();
Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();

// URL
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://www.remoteservice.com/service");

// Timeouts
requestContext.put(BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5000);
requestContext.put(BindingProviderProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, 30000);

// Authentication
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "user");
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");
```

Comment: This means you cannot deploy an application without change to dev, test and prod without using the same password on each system?

Comment: @DavidLakatos No David, you can save the values (username, password, etc) elsewhere outside your application (database, properties file, etc) and change those without build/deploy. My code has static values but that is a code simplification just demonstrating how you perform the client configuration. The point here is that WebLogic does not provide an internal configuration for JAX-WS. Usually we store properties in the database or in an XML file. You can use cache or not, depending on your scenario. Usually it is a good idea to save it in memory since such values do not change often.

Comment: My main approach would be to alter some application property via Weblogic deployment plan during deployment without altering the code or using external resources (eg. property file, db). Do you think it is feasible?

Comment: @DavidLakatos I've never used that feature before. It seems it would work if you manage to use a custom XML of your own bundled in the application, but I'm not so sure if it was designed for that. It seems to be Java EE standard (JSR-88). I'm gonna give it a try someday, and learn about it.